# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression in SQL Server

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have some SQL code, and when I run it, I get an error:

```
SELECT AVG (DISTINCT E.salary) AS avrage
FROM aircraft AS A, certified AS C, employees AS E
WHERE A.cruisingrange > 1000 
  AND A.aid = C.aid 
  AND C.eid = E.eid
```

Error:

[image]

How can I fix this error?

Comment: your error showing `count` where your current query is with `avg`.

Comment: Your error doesn't match the SQL you posted.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: `AVG(DISTINCT)` is basically never the right solution to a problem.  What are you trying to calculate?

Comment: I want to calculate the average salary of pilots and I don't want Repetitious salaries to be in the calculation @GordonLinoff

Comment: @MahdiAspanani . . . Multiple pilots could have the same salary and the average would be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

MS Access does not directly support `DISTINCT` syntax inside of an aggregate function.  One workaround here would be to take the average of a subquery which finds the distinct salaries:

```
SELECT AVG(salary) AS avrage
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT E.salary
    FROM (aircraft AS A
    INNER JOIN certified AS C ON A.aid = C.aid)
    INNER JOIN employees AS E ON C.eid = E.eid
    WHERE A.cruisingrange > 1000
) t;
```

Note that I have also converted your old school implicit join syntax to modern explicit join syntax.  This is the preferred way of writing SQL these days.

Comment: You missed the parenthesis for this to run in Access.